# Is there an alternative to PHP's strip_tags()

Tags: php

The [`strip_tags()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) tells us that all the tags except the that in the second parameter are stripped. The operation this function performs is totally opposite to its name. It should have been named `strip_all_tags_except()`.

Let's forget about the name and come to what I want to ask. I want the functionality of removing only the tags I mention in the second parameter. ie. I want the following to strip tags `<iframe><script><style><embed><object>` and allow all others.

```
my_strip_tags($data,'<iframe><script><style><embed><object>');
```

It's pretty opposite to what `strip_tags()` does.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: Did you read the comments on the documentation page you linked to, that has at least 2 examples of how to do what you're asking?

Comment: if you want to sanitize user input and allow some html tags you should consider a library that does this because strip tags (or a similar function that allows you to chose tags to allow) won't filter attributes and those can also be used for xss injection

Comment: I fail to see how the name is wrong: `$stripped = strip_tags($html);` strips all the tags, as advertised. The exempted tags option is just that... an **OPTION**. If you don't use it, then the function strips everything.

Comment: You might want to update anything you've used my answer in - I found a big security hole. It's patched now, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated 2012-06-23; major security flaw.**

Here's a class from another project that should do what you're looking for:

```
final class Filter {
    private function __construct() {}

    const SafeTags = 'a abbr acronym address b bdo big blockquote br caption center cite code col colgroup dd del dfn dir div dl dt em font h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 hr i img ins kbd legend li ol p pre q s samp small span strike strong sub sup table tbody td tfoot th thead tr tt u ul var article aside figure footer header nav section rp rt ruby dialog hgroup mark time';
    const SafeAttributes = 'href src title alt type rowspan colspan lang';
    const URLAttributes  = 'href src';

    public static function HTML($html) {
        # Get array representations of the safe tags and attributes:
        $safeTags = explode(' ', self::SafeTags);
        $safeAttributes = explode(' ', self::SafeAttributes);
        $urlAttributes = explode(' ', self::URLAttributes);

        # Parse the HTML into a document object:
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML('<div>' . $html . '</div>');

        # Loop through all of the nodes:
        $stack = new SplStack();
        $stack->push($dom->documentElement);

        while($stack->count() > 0) {
            # Get the next element for processing:
            $element = $stack->pop();

            # Add all the element's child nodes to the stack:
            foreach($element->childNodes as $child) {
                if($child instanceof DOMElement) {
                    $stack->push($child);
                }
            }

            # And now, we do the filtering:
            if(!in_array(strtolower($element->nodeName), $safeTags)) {
                # It's not a safe tag; unwrap it:
                while($element->hasChildNodes()) {
                    $element->parentNode->insertBefore($element->firstChild, $element);
                }

                # Finally, delete the offending element:
                $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
            } else {
                # The tag is safe; now filter its attributes:
                for($i = 0; $i < $element->attributes->length; $i++) {
                    $attribute = $element->attributes->item($i);
                    $name = strtolower($attribute->name);

                    if(!in_array($name, $safeAttributes) || (in_array($name, $urlAttributes) && substr($attribute->value, 0, 7) !== 'http://')) {
                        # Found an unsafe attribute; remove it:
                        $element->removeAttribute($attribute->name);
                        $i--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        # Finally, return the safe HTML, minus the DOCTYPE, <html> and <body>:
        $html  = $dom->saveHTML();
        $start = strpos($html, '<div>');
        $end   = strrpos($html, '</div>');

        return substr($html, $start + 5, $end - $start - 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: This function can strip tags, but keeps the text that is inside those tags, which may not be what you want.

Comment: @Dylan: Well, like I said, it's for another project - and that was exactly what I wanted, personally. (If you're worried about the contents of `<script>` tags appearing, they have no business being there in the first place, so...)

Comment: @minitech: Would love to see having you a github account linked on your profile page ;)

Comment: This doesn't play well with UTF-8 foreign characters. I get entities based of scrambled iso-8859-1 characters.

Comment: @tim: Don't use PHP if you're even remotely interested in that stuff :P

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't happen at all.

`strip_tags` is only usable if used without any parameters. Otherwise you will have an XSS in any tag allowed.

As a matter of fact, your concern should be not only tags but also *attributes*. So, use some sort of HTML purifier instead.

Answer (score 1):

I usually work with htmLawed lib, you can use it to filter, secure & sanitize HTML

http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/more.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think the strip_tags() functionality matches its name.  It's all a matter of perspective.  :-)  Without a second parameter, it strips all tags.  The second parameter provides exceptions to the basic functionality.

What you want seems to be `strip_some_tags()`.

What about just doing it with a regexp?

```
function strip_some_tags($input, $taglist) {
  $output=$input;
  foreach ($taglist as $thistag) {
    if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', $thistag)) {
      $patterns=array(
        '/' . "<".$thistag."\/?>" . '/',
        '/' . "<\/".$thistag.">" . '/'
      );
    } else
    if (preg_match('/^<[a-z]+>$/i', $thistag)) {
      $patterns=array(
        '/' . str_replace('>', "?>", $thistag) . '/',
        '/' . str_replace('<', "<\/?", $thistag) . '/'
      );
    }
    else {
      $patterns=array();
    }
    $output=preg_replace($patterns, "", $output);
  }
  return $output;
}

$to_strip=array( "iframe", "script", "style", "embed", "object" );

$sampletext="Testing. <object>Am I an object?</object>\n";

print strip_some_tags($sampletext, $to_strip);
```

Returns:

```
Testing. Am I an object?
```

Of course, this just strips the tags, not the stuff between them.  Is that what you want?  You didn't specify in your question.

Comment: A wise man on another question said that regexes are perfectly usable on HTML as long as you don't have to ask how.  :-)

Comment: @ghoti: You mean... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491

Comment: @BoltClock - that's the one, yes.

Comment: Thanks for replying.Yes, I just want to strip the tags. stripping the stuff is also something I would need in future.