# safely load HTML from user into textarea

Tags: php, html, post

I'm using TinyMCE 4 on a project, where I need to be able to pre-populate the textarea with HTML that was submitted through POST (for server-side error handling without deleting all their work)  I know that a textarea works mostly like a  tag, in that HTML inside is not parsed into DOM, so most sites show the demo:

`<textarea name="demo"><?=$_POST['demo']?></textarea>`

but what happens when a user submits HTML that includes an unmatched `<textarea>` or `</textarea>` tag?

Is there a standard way to manage this risk?

Comment: TinyMCE may well have an internal way to handle this, i don't use it but its brother cfkeditor does. you should check its documentation before trying any of the suggestions below

Comment: Take a look at http://htmlpurifier.org it's the best!

Answer (score 1):

use `htmlspecialchars($_POST['demo'])` in php when outputing

Comment: This won't work, because the textarea needs to contain valid HTML.  the final submitted values from TinyMCE are valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Remove only the `<textarea>` tags from the user input.  Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165895/php-strip-tags-remove-only-certain-tags-and-their-contents) post using regular expressions.  It tells you how to remove only certain tags (unlike `htmlentities`) which removes all tags.

Comment: The regexes listed here can be defeated by malformed input like `</ textarea >`.  Overall, using regexes to parse HTML is usually a very bad idea, because of the looseness of the HTML standard.

Comment: In this case, you first just need to trim the white space from the input with `str_replace()`.  Other instances should not fall outside the standard or browser interpreters.

Comment: that is only one example of many potential abuses.  it is extremely easy to defeat most regex based html parsers.

Answer (score 0):

htmlentities function will replace every html caracter (such as <) to one that will display correctly but wont break your html.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: This won't work, because the textarea needs to contain valid HTML.  the final submitted values from TinyMCE are valid HTML.

Comment: This will work. Try it.
<textarea name="demo"><?=htmlentities($_POST['demo'])?></textarea>

Comment: it does work with tinyMCE's default settings, as they convert encoded characters, but that poses a separate issue of not knowing how many encodings we've been through, and did the user want the entities as entities.  It also makes the non-javascript fallback differ from the javascript input, making it a questionable design choice.

Comment: Well, tinyMCE decode the caracter and re-encode it uppon submittion. So basically the html will always be in normal state in your database/file. So you sould never have any issue with that. And the user can click Html on tinymce to view the html or copy-paste it as html. So everything will works. Javascript will also return an unencoded value of it (so if you encode it in the textarea, getting value in javascript will return <, unless you look for the innerHTML value.

Answer (score 0):

Use xmp tag instead of textarea. It will display html as itself.

Eg: http://dadinck.x10.mx/xmp.html

Comment: that just shifts the issue to one where the user might enter `</xmp>`

Comment: strip xmp from the input. It's comparatively less used than textarea.