# Replace html tag with class and var php

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to replace a string that I get from database. I want to replace `span` by an empty string.

My string is like so:

```
<p><span class="coursehours">x horas lectivas</span>
<span class="coursehours">x horas prácticas</span></p>
```

`X` is a number and I want to remove the p tag entire.

How do I should do?

Comment: What is your expected outcome? What have you tried?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165895/php-strip-tags-remove-only-certain-tags-and-their-contents

Comment: Take a look at "dom parsers" and "regular expressions".

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work too?

```js
var text = "<p> <span class='coursehours'>x horas lectivas</span> <span class='coursehours'>x horas prácticas</span></p>";
var str = text.trim().substring(3, text.length - 4);
alert(str.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry because I have explained wrong

What I wanted to eliminate only those span

Seems with this is fixed

```
preg_replace('#<span class="coursehours">(.*?)</span>#', '', $string);
```

Thanks to all !

Answer (score -1):

Try stripping HTML and PHP tags from a string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Something like this:

```
$str = "your string";
$str = strip_tags($str);
```